# BJT Transistor Simulation at Multisim: Why is Ie not equal to Ib+Ic?

Tags: transistors, bjt, simulation, multisim

[image: Simulation results of Ie,Ib,Ic]

I used current probes and Single Frequency AC Analysis (where Frequency = Frequency of the AC Voltage Source), but the I<sub>e</sub>, I<sub>b</sub>, I<sub>c</sub> show that I<sub>e</sub> is not equal to I<sub>b</sub> + I<sub>c</sub>?

Hope someone can clarify :)

[image]

Comment: Yet another reminder about why I threw away Multisim about one month after purchasing it. Seems like it hasn't gotten better, since.

Comment: If these are phasors, you need to account for phase to know whether they add up or not.

Comment: @ThePhoton There is that. But... I've used Multisim. It regularly produced, a decade ago anyway, numbers that didn't add up like this. So, maybe you are right. I do see caps in the circuit. But I have to say other Spice programs have far fewer issues like this, so far as my experience goes. I was so angry, that I decided then and there to NEVER look at Multisim ever, ever again. It was that bad. (Maybe I should revisit it. But I've really no interest.)

Comment: I'm with jonk on this. I also threw away my Multisim copy a couple of years back. The LTspice is enough for me.

Comment: is that a million volts in column 2 ?

Answer (score 1):

In AC analysis, you need to account for the phase angles of any voltages or currents you might be measuring, not just their magnitudes.

A BJT has significant parasitic capacitances among its terminals, and at 1 MHz, a significant amount of reactive current can flow between them in addition to what we think of as the normal operation of the semiconductor, particularly between the base and collector terminals.

Answer (score 1):

That's just the nature of complex arithmetic, you can't simply add the magnitude of the complex value.

Any spice program is going to produce a similar result to yours if you ignore the phase angle of the AC currents. Consider the following LT Spice simulation:
[image]

Here the magnitude of Ie doesn't equal Ib + Ic.

However, if we apply complex arithmetic all is well:

[image]

Note, the blue trace is hidden because it is identical to the green trace expression of Ib + Ic.